# debug FileNotFoundException in depth C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, filestream

I'm having issues with random FileNotFoundExceptions when i'm creating a FileStream. The filepath is correct, the file exist, still i get FileNotFoundException at random times. How can i debug this more in detail? I'm running a Windows Mobile 6 project and this is the exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '\Program Files\xxx\xxx\xxx-11133.bin'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync, String msgPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
```

This is the method that throws the exception:

```
internal static FInstance ReadAndDecrypt(string key, string fiId)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(FullFilePath(fiId));

            FileStream fileStream = null;
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;
            GZipInputStream zipStream = null;

            try
            {
                int time = Environment.TickCount;
                fileStream = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FInstance));
                var FInstance = (FInstance)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);

                return Instance;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e);
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (fileStream != null)
                    fileStream.Close();
            }

        }
```

I can't think of anything that could cause this, is there any way to debug this deeper?

Comment: Are you calling it multiple times for the same file? Are you sure that there aren't any other programs/code that is modifying that file?

Comment: @Hans, there are no drive letters in Windows CE.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging this should be straightforward.  Add the following into your code right before your `try/catch` block:

```
if((!fileInfo.Exists) && (Debugger.IsAttached))
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

This will get you to the state where the file isn't there.  You should be checking for existence before opening the file in your production code anyway to protect against things like the file being deleted or in use while you app is already running.